# Knockout binding doesn't update using array of simple observables

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of strings in my view model.  To edit them, I want each to appear as an `<li>` with a textbox, and a `<button>` to remove the item.  So, for the list `['A', 'B']`, I want something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: titles">
    <li>
        <input value="A" data-bind="value:$data" />
        <button data-bind="click: $root.remove">remove</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value="B" data-bind="value:$data" />
        <button data-bind="click: $root.remove">remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: add">add</button>
```

I can create that initially, but am not getting updates to the values to reflect in the view model, and can't get the remove buttons working.

I initially had an `observableArray` of plain strings, then updated to an `observableArray` of `observable` strings.  With the plain strings, the remove button worked, but it, predictably, didn't update the view model.

**I've setup a JS fiddle with the issue fairly isolated: http://jsfiddle.net/bdukes/uvyH3/2/**

If there's an established or better way of doing this, I'd love to know.

Also, as an unrelated (and less important) issue, the `stringifyJson` utility always seems to give me empty results for each item in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knockout does not currently work well with an array of pure observables (issue logged [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/482)).

To make this work properly, you need your items to be objects that hold observables like:

```
{ val: ko.observable("something") }
```

Here is your fiddle updated to use these type of objects: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GgFa9/

Comment: I'd wondered if I'd have to do that, just didn't feel right.  Thanks for the fix, and for letting me know that it's a known issue.

Comment: It appears that the issue mentioned was addressed in knockout 3.0.0