# Handling observables in an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

*Note: This is* ***not*** *a question about ObservableArrays.*

Let's say I have the following viewmodel:

```
var viewmodel = {
    arrayOfBooleans: [
        ko.observable(false),
        ko.observable(false),
        ko.observable(false)
    ]
}
```

And a view like so:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: arrayOfBooleans">
    <button data-bind="click: ????">Set to true</button>
</div>
```

What can I do inside the `foreach` to get the `<button>` to set the observable to true when clicked?  Using `data-bind="click: someFunction"`, the first argument `someFunction` gets is the unwrapped values of observables in the array (not the observables themselves), and seemingly no way to get back at the observables or to pass custom arguments.

Comment: Is there a reason the array isn't an `observablearray`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout binding doesn't update using array of simple observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621008/knockout-binding-doesnt-update-using-array-of-simple-observables)

Comment: @Tyrsius: Unfortunately, ObservableArrays are used to detect changes to the order or membership of the array, not manage the state of their members.  For this situation, I don't care to notify anything about changes to the array itself.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: This does seem to be the same issue; is there a good way to mark them as related?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will give some idea .

```
var viewmodel = {
  var self = this;
 self.arrayOfBooleans = ko.observableArray([]);

 self.arrayOfBooleans.push(new _newBoolean());
 self.arrayOfBooleans.push(new _newBoolean());
 self.arrayOfBooleans.push(new _newBoolean());

 function _newBoolean() { 
   self.one = ko.observable(false);
 }

self.setToTrue = function(index){
   self.arrayOfBooleans()[index].one(true);
 };
 }
```

**If you want it as button**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: arrayOfBooleans">
  <button data-bind="click: $root.setToTrue($parent.arrayOfBooleans.indexOf($data))"> 
   Set to true
  </button>
  <input type=hidden data-bind="value:one" />
</div>
```

**If you want it as radio button than it is much more simple**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: arrayOfBooleans">
  <span>Set To True</span><input type=radio data-bind="value:one" />
</div>
```

**If you like this..Please Click uplink**
**or**
**If it solves your problem .. Mark this as answer**

Comment: Not a bad way to go, Boss.  I think the simpler solution is posted in [Knockout binding doesn't update using array of simple observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621008/knockout-binding-doesnt-update-using-array-of-simple-observables).